# differentiate betwwen forward and backward navigation on a page Ionic2

Tags: ionic2

How can I differentiate that whether a page comes into view from forward or backward navigation. I want to run some code only if it is forward navigation.

Comment: What if you run that code in the constructor? It won't be executed again if you go back to that page, and assuming it's a page that you `push` (instead of setting it as root) it will be executed every time the user navigates to that page.

Answer (score 0):

**CASE 1 :-** Say you are navigating from 1 page to another - Forward. I.e. using `navCtrl.push(Page,params)`.

Here, you can put your code in `constructor(){}`. *Code in your constructor always gets executed when you push/navigate to a page - Forward.* (Rather than push, you can also reset the stack to a rootpage. This is valid then also.)

**CASE 2 :-** Say you are navigating back from a page - Backward. I.e. manually going back by user in the app or using `navCtrl.pop()`.

Here, I think, there is **NOT** any in-built way to recognise if you have navigated on a back page. Here you need to build your own logic.

For e.g, PageA -> PageB is your navigation. I have used `localStorage` variable to set to some value, (e.g `localStorage.setItem('isPushed',true)`) when navigating from  PageA -> PageB.

Now, in PageA I have written this code using `ionViewWillEnter()`:

```
ionViewWillEnter(){
    if(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('isPushed')){
        localStorage.setItem('isPushed',false);
        // Your Code to be executed when entering to back page.
    }
}
```

*`ionViewWillEnter()` always gets executed when the particular page is navigated.* So, my idea here is just to detect if it is navigated from a next page to a back page. Hope this helps. :)

**NOTE :** I have not handled all the conditions related to this. That you have to work it out. This is just an idea of logic to use.